# Create directory in Remote Desktop with a bash function

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have this function for connecting to a Remote Desktop through SSH and perform some actions there, but I cannot really figure out the syntax and if it's possible to do so.

```
#Simple example
simple () {
ssh $1 "cd /home/ubuntu/Desktop; var=/home/ubuntu/Desktop/$2; mkdir $var; cd $var; pwd";
}
```

When I run the above script I get an error `missing operand
Try 'mkdir --help' for more information.
/home/ubuntu`

What I want to do is connect to the Remote Desktop, create a new directory `/home/ubuntu/$2`, cd to it and print it.

P.S. Sorry about that, I forgot to mention that there is going to be another positional argument.

Comment: See also [How to pass the second argument in the bash function](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/396474)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole string `"cd /home/ubuntu/Desktop;
var=/home/ubuntu/Desktop/abcd; mkdir $var; cd $var; pwd"` is expanded
client-side, before being sent to the remote host. In the client
environment, `var` is not set, causing `$var` to expand to the empty
string and, in turn, causing the commands run on the remote host to be
`mkdir` and `cd`, with no parameter.

A simple fix is to single-quote your string, forcing expansion to
happen on the remote host:

```
ssh "$1" 'cd /home/ubuntu/Desktop; var=/home/ubuntu/Desktop/abcd; mkdir $var; cd $var; pwd'
```

If, in your real use case, parts of the string need to be expanded
client-side, you can use double quotes and protect just those
variables that should be expanded remotely:

```
ssh "$1" "cd /home/ubuntu/Desktop; var=/home/ubuntu/Desktop/abcd; mkdir \$var; cd \$var; pwd"
```

There are other ways to do it; one of the various styles of heredocs
will probably be suitable as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I disregarded to mention that instead of `abcd`, there is a positional argument. Does that change a lot the answer?

Comment: Then, more fine-grained quoting or escaping is needed. I will update my answer to account for this.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it (Included in my answer to your question on SuperUser) is with a heredoc:

```
simple.func () {

    ssh ${1}@${2} <<'EOF'
    cd /home/jbutryn/test
    DIR_VAR='/home/jbutryn/test/tmp'
    mkdir "$DIR_VAR"
    cd "$DIR_VAR"
    pwd
EOF

}
```

As dhag pointed out we must escape any variables on the local machine so they are sent to the remote machine as is and expanded there.  Single quoting the `EOF` delimiter accomplishes this.  I've also added the `$2` parameter for the hostname/IP.  I'm not sure how you were running the function but now it's `simple.func [user] [hostname]`

Since you need to pass a local positional parameter you can do this instead:

```
simple.func () {

    ssh ${1} <<EOF
    cd /home/jbutryn/test
    DIR_VAR="/home/jbutryn/test/${2}"
    mkdir '$DIR_VAR'
    cd '$DIR_VAR'
    pwd
EOF

}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer and the previous one, but I was not able to get the expected output for the other question, I don't know why through EOF. I'll give a try for this one.

Comment: Make sure the final `EOF` is at the start of the line, you cannot indent it with a tab or any whitespace.